# Vue 2 Display All Content After Specfic Time

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

Using Vue 2 on Laravel 5.3

I would like to add a loading icon which covers the whole page for 3 seconds allowing all rendering happened, then showing the content after 3 seconds. However, without or with adding the `div v-show="!loading"` as shown below, the content actually flashed for around half second before it gone disappeared, then after 3 seconds it appears again. So I think there is an unexpected flash at the start when the page is loaded. I read a bit about `v-cloak` online but it seems only solve short flash of `{{}}` ?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="loading" class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
    </transition>
    <div v-show="!loading">
      <slot>

        <!-- Main Content -->

      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        loading:true
      }
    },
    props:[
    ],
    mounted(){
      var vm = this
      vm.loaded()
      LoadingEvent.$on('loading', function(loading){
        vm.loading = loading
      })
    },
    updated(){
    },
    methods:{
      loaded(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          LoadingEvent.$emit('loading',false);
        }, 1000);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both v-if and v-else inside  `transition` like following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="loading" class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
      <div v-else>
        <slot>

         <!-- Main Content -->

       </slot>
     </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @saurabh, it does help some other of my problems. But this still does not fix the half second flash of content at the start of the page loading.

Comment: @warmjaijai possible to create a fiddle of it

Comment: sorry that Im not sure how to use fiddle. On top of that the transition effect does not apply when I use v-else div to wrap slot

Comment: Oh, I am also aware of that if we use v-else, the content will only start rendering when v-else is executed, so it does not serve the purpose of rendering during the loading icon is on

Comment: @warmjaijai check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/suq8k6ob/ . You can always use v-show as well instead of v-if/v-else